# python program error while combine two program

Tags: python-3.x

i have wrote two program, one is tic tac toe,one is guest number, and it is fine when run separately and when i combine them( my aim is when to people win in the guest number game, the people can pick a box in tic tac toe)
It work normally and when it start to select to second box, the error occur
it is show asz follow

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\try3.py", line 207, in 
winner = single_game(options[choice-1])
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\try3.py", line 125, in single_game
player_pos[cur_player].append(move)
KeyError: <**main**.Player object at 0x000001D6C01CC730>

can anyone see what wrong with my program. Thanks
import random
from random import randint

```
class Player():

def __init__(self, player_name):
self.name = player_name
self.score = 0
self.guess = 0

def enterGuess(self,rand, play):

if play == True:
  self.guess = int(input(self.name+ " enter a guess 1-100:"))
    
if self.guess == rand:
    print ("Correct Guess")
    play = False
    self.score = self.score + 1
        
elif self.guess < rand:
    print ("Too low")
        
else:
    print ("Too high")
  
return play
def playGame():
player1.score = 0
player1.guess = 0
player2.score = 0
player2.guess = 0
randNum = randint(1,100)
play = True
print ("\nNew game")

while play:
    play=player1.enterGuess(randNum, play)
    play=player2.enterGuess(randNum, play)



def coinToss():
flip = random.randint(0, 1)
if (flip == 0):
    return("Head")
else:
    return("Tail")
print(coinToss)
def print_tic_tac_toe(values):
print("\n")
print("\t     |     |")
print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}".format(values[0], values[1], values[2]))
print('\t_____|_____|_____')

print("\t     |     |")
print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}".format(values[3], values[4], values[5]))
print('\t_____|_____|_____')

print("\t     |     |")

print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}".format(values[6], values[7], values[8]))
print("\t     |     |")
print("\n")

def print_scoreboard(score_board):
print("\t--------------------------------")
print("\t              SCOREBOARD       ")
print("\t--------------------------------")

players = list(score_board.keys())
print("\t   ", players[0], "\t    ", score_board[players[0]])
print("\t   ", players[1], "\t    ", score_board[players[1]])

print("\t--------------------------------\n")

def check_win(player_pos, cur_player):


soln = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]


for x in soln:
    if all(y in player_pos[cur_player] for y in x):

      
        return True   
return False       

def check_draw(player_pos):
if len(player_pos['X']) + len(player_pos['O']) == 9:
    return True
return False       

def single_game(cur_player):

values = [' ' for x in range(9)]
 
player_pos = {'X':[], 'O':[]}
 
while True:
    print_tic_tac_toe(values)
     
    try:
        print("The player ", cur_player, " turn. Which box? : ", end="")
        move = int(input()) 
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again")
        continue

   
    if move < 1 or move > 9:
        print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again")
        continue

    
    if values[move-1] != ' ':
        print("Place already filled. Try again!!")
        continue

    
    values[move-1] = cur_player

  
    player_pos[cur_player].append(move)

 
    if check_win(player_pos, cur_player):
        print_tic_tac_toe(values)
        print( cur_player, " has won the game!!")     
        print("\n")
        return cur_player

   
    if check_draw(player_pos):
        print_tic_tac_toe(values)
        print("Game Drawn")
        print("\n")
        return 'D'

    playGame()
    if int(player1.score)>int(player2.score):
        cur_player = player1
    else:
        cur_player = player2

if __name__ == "__main__":

print ("Player 1")
player1=Player(input("Enter name:"))

print ("Player 2")
player2=Player(input("Enter name:"))
playGame()
if int(player1.score)>int(player2.score):
    cur_player = player1
else:
    cur_player = player2

player_choice = {'X' : "", 'O' : ""}


options = ['X', 'O']

score_board = {player1: 0, player2: 0}
print_scoreboard(score_board)

while True:

   
    print("Turn to choose for", cur_player)
    print("Enter 1 for X")
    print("Enter 2 for O")
    print("Enter 3 to Quit")

   
    try:
        choice = int(input())   
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again\n")
        continue

   
    if choice == 1:
        player_choice['X'] = cur_player
        if cur_player == player1:
            player_choice['O'] = player2
        else:
            player_choice['O'] = player1

    elif choice == 2:
        player_choice['O'] = cur_player
        if cur_player == player1:
            player_choice['X'] = player2
        else:
            player_choice['X'] = player1
     
    elif choice == 3:
        print("Final Scores")
        print_scoreboard(score_board)
        break  

    else:
        print("Wrong Choice!!!! Try Again\n")

    
    winner = single_game(options[choice-1])
     
   
    if winner != 'D' :
        player_won = player_choice[winner]
        score_board[player_won] = score_board[player_won] + 1

    print_scoreboard(score_board)
```

Comment: Please check the indentation.

Comment: Could you please try indenting the program

Comment: and please see how to create a [mre]